# Handling large data generated by a script file (using parallelization in Mathematica)

Tags: parallelization, data, memory, scripting, computational-complexity

I want to write a script file `Script_file.m` which I am going to run on a server and collect all the data in a file named `Data_file.txt` by the command

```
math -script Script_file.m > Data_file.txt
```

The script uses parallelization to use Mathematica in its full potential to obtain better time management. As the actual function is pretty complicated, so I am trying to mimic it in a very analogous manner. Let's say that the function is simply `Log` function defined in this fashion

```
func = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Log[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

The actual function takes 12 arguments and returns 12 outputs, analogous to

```
Module[{randNum, funcValue, data},
randNum = RandomReal[{10^-10, 10^-6}, 12];
funcValue = func/@randNum;
data = Flatten[{randNum, funcValue}];
data
]
```

So the `data` contains a list of 24 elements, out of which the first 12 are the arguments of the function (in actual case) and the last 12 contains the output of the function. This process has to be repeated 10^9 times resulting in a 10^9 by 24 matrix (list of list). The repetition is checked (using smaller numbers) by implementing `ParallelTable[Module code block, 10^3]//Print` and the script runs fine printing the values to the file. But the storage of such a large (10^9 by 24) matrix is exceeding the memory of the system. Some statistics regarding memory usage (tracked by `/usr/bin/time -f %M` command)

for `10^4`: Max memory (in kbytes): 296728

for `10^5`: Max memory (in kbytes): 1333648

It is clear that the memory consumption easily surpasses even for `5*10^7` iterations in a server with 128 GB ram. I tried with `ParallelDo` command with `Print` option inside the Module code block. I have also tried to use `OpenWrite` and `Write` commands for printing to file which resulted in `Write::strml` or `OutputStream` related error. Using `Print[data]` inside the Module block results in an error due to accessing the file in a parallel manner which was mentioned in some of the answers related to parallelization. I tried other methods also which sometimes resulted in a data file containing values in a messy way without being extractable. There was also some errors related to not having `FrontEnd` to do such printing iteratively wich I could not fix with `UsingFrontEnd` command. Also, `.txt` extension may not be suitable to store such matrices. I used `.dat` and `.csv` extension but the data is unorganised containing commas and brackets everywhere which is difficult to work with after importing. I have seen `.mat` or `.mx` file extensions to store tensor type data and dump saving but was not able to apply these in my case.

Is there any way to manage the large data without storing it within Mathematica (while the script is running) and writing to a file to free up unnecessary memory while using parallelization in a script file? Or maybe some other procedure to handle such cases. Any suggestion or comment or link to similar posts which I might have missed will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand: Why can't you store intermediate data in `.mx` files? Yes, you cannot print iteratively to such a format. But every thread can collect the data of a chunk in a separate matrix and every now and export it to some `.mx` file with a file name that reflects which thread created it and chunk-counter.

Comment: Btw.: Using anything front end related in a parallelized loop is very counterproductive, because the front end would reside only on one core, so it is the most limited ressource.

Comment: Moreover, are you sure that you need all this data at the same point in time? For example, this would not be necessary if you just want to compute some weighted sum over it. If you require all this data, one may ask oneself whether there might be some structure in it that allows for compression. (But there is likely not much chance if the data is essentially random.)

Comment: Thanks, @HenrikSchumacher for such valuable comments. I do need the whole data for analysing and plotting columns with respect to some other column after the computation is done. The `DumpSave` command is not very clear to me as of now. As you mentioned in your first comment, if using `.mx` files can be an option to dump data to hard disk freeing up ram usage in MMA  running a script in parallelization, I request you to explain this process by some code for a very small number of iteration so that I can understand the concept behind it.

Comment: Well, simply do `Export[filename<> ".mx", data] ` to store the expression `data` (e.g., a matrix) to the desired file. The format is deduced from the file extension in this case. If `data` is the `i`-th chunk in the `k`-th thread, you could simply use `filename = 
  FileNameJoin[{path, 
    filebasename <> "_" <> IntegerString[k, 10, 3] <> "_" <> 
     IntegerString[i, 10, 9]}];` where `filebasename` is just a string with the base file name. (`<>` joins strings and `IntegerString` allows you to place leading zeros into a number string).

Comment: You can reimport the data from file with `data = Import[filename]`.

Comment: I could not get what is meant by `i-`th chunk. Moreover, I replaced `k` in your code above with `$KernelID` to denote the thread number if I understood it correctly. It resulted in `A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end` errors. I have tried using `UsingFrontEnd` command but it did not help. I am doing all these codes in a `.m` file as I mentioned previously. I need to run all these codes as a script later. It may be quite troublesome for you, but if possible, I request you to copy these codes in your MMA as a `.m` file to get a sense of the problem.